# Oracle : Date Checking is used last 6months or not

Tags: oracle, date

I have table "CONTACT", if contact createddate is not used last 6 months in some other table i need to remove the Contact, can anyone help to resolve this?

Comment: I understand you have a question.  But I have no idea what you're asking.  What does it mean to you to have a date used in some other table in a period of time?  A reproducible test case (ddl, dml, expected results) would probably be helpful.

Comment: Here you can find some suggestions on [ask] and how to build a [mcve]

Comment: @JustinCave 2 tables - CONTACT and ORDERS. if contact is created today and contactId is used for any Orders in ORDERS table means np. If contact id is not used for any Orders in Last 6 months means i need to delete the entry in CONTACT Table.

Comment: Please edit the question with these details, do not add comments. The table structure, some sample data and what you tried so far should be included too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to identify contacts that have not had an order in the last 6 months

```
select c.contact_id
  from contact c
 where not exists( select 1
                     from orders o
                    where o.contact_id = c.contact_id
                      and o.order_date > add_months(sysdate,-6) )
```

To delete the rows

```
delete from contact c
 where not exists( select 1
                     from orders o
                    where o.contact_id = c.contact_id
                      and o.order_date > add_months(sysdate,-6) )
```

That being said, it seems unlikely that you'd want to do this.  If you have a reasonable data model, deleting a contact would mean that you had to delete any order older than 6 months which seems like a bad idea.  Perhaps it would make more sense to set an `active_flag` to 'N' in that case.